# Problems Install MobileFirst Platform Studio in RAD 9.0.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, rational-rsa

I need and try to install the IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio plugin in the Rational Software Developer for WebSphere 9.0.0 application, but I can not.

I've tried using the Help Menu - Installing new software, any URL I enter are valid, not located in the repository

I could install it in RAD 9.0 through the Help menu - Eclipse Marketplace ... and I get to locate the IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio software, but when trying to install shows three packages (IBM Dojo Mobile Tools, IBM Jquery Mobile Tools and IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio). I try all possible combinations with packages and trying to install it shows me an error.

Detalle.

No se puede completar la instalación debido a una dependencia en conflicto.
Software que se está instalando: IBM Dojo Mobile Tools 7.0.0.00-20150312-0731 (com.ibm.imp.dojo.tools.licensed.feature.feature.group 7.0.0.00-20150312-0731)
Software instalado actualmente: IBM Software Delivery Platform 2015.3.23.152120 (IBM Software Delivery Platform com.ibm.sdp.eclipse.ide 2015.3.23.152120)

Sólo se puede instalar uno de los siguientes a la vez:
Core 1.1.0.v20150311_2119 (com.ibm.faceted.project.wizard.core 1.1.0.v20150311_2119)
Core 1.0.200.v20130416_1206 (com.ibm.faceted.project.wizard.core 1.0.200.v20130416_1206)

No se puede satisfacer la dependencia:
De: IBM Software Delivery Platform 2015.3.23.152120 (IBM Software Delivery Platform com.ibm.sdp.eclipse.ide 2015.3.23.152120)
A: com.ibm.etools.wtp.extensions.feature.feature.group [1.0.100.v20130416_1206]

No se puede satisfacer la dependencia:
De: WTP Extensions 1.0.100.v20130416_1206 (com.ibm.etools.wtp.extensions.feature.feature.group 1.0.100.v20130416_1206)
A: com.ibm.faceted.project.wizard.core [1.0.200.v20130416_1206]

No se puede satisfacer la dependencia:
De: IBM Dojo Mobile Tools 7.0.0.00-20150312-0731 (com.ibm.imp.dojo.tools.licensed.feature.feature.group 7.0.0.00-20150312-0731)
A: com.ibm.imp.tools.wce.feature.feature.group 7.0.0

No se puede satisfacer la dependencia:
De: IBM Mobile Application Tools 7.0.0.00-20150312-0731 (com.ibm.imp.feature.feature.group 7.0.0.00-20150312-0731)
A: com.ibm.imp.worklight.ui [7.0.0.00-20150312-0731]

No se puede satisfacer la dependencia:
De: IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.0.0.00-20150312-0731 (com.ibm.imp.tools.wce.feature.feature.group 7.0.0.00-20150312-0731)
A: com.ibm.imp.feature.feature.group 7.0.0

No se puede satisfacer la dependencia:
De: Ui 7.0.0.00-20150312-0731 (com.ibm.imp.worklight.ui 7.0.0.00-20150312-0731)
A: bundle com.ibm.faceted.project.wizard.core [1.1.0,2.0.0)

I've tried with a zip with the plugin, I have introduced in RAD 9.0 plugins folder, but to restart the program, nothing happens.

Please, could give me some solution to the problem that I have?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is URL Repository: WorkLight - <https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/install/Asdasd>
WorkLight - <http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/Asdas>
WorkLight - <http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile->solutions/>
WorkLight - <http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=298621>
Worklight - <http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-worklight-developer->edition#.U6RHHu1Du2Y
Worklight - <http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/WORKLIGHT>

Answer (score 0):

That is an unsupported configuration. MobileFirst Platform Foundation Studio 7.0 does not install into a Rtional Applicaiton Developer instance (also known as eclipse shell sharing).  They must be installed into their own eclipse image.