# Create APK from RAD 9.0 or Eclipse Juno 4.2.2

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, eclipse-juno, ibm-rad

I am working with IBM RAD 9.0 (priority) and I have some HTML5/CSS3 templates. I would like to create a APK with these templates and to be able to se them with an Android  dispositive.

Question: with the IBM plugin MobileFirst Platform Studio, it is possible to generate the APK from IBM RAD 9.0 and from Eclipse Juno 4.2.2?

Answer (score 0):

RAD 9.0 is unsupported with MobileFirst, see this question: [Problems Install MobileFirst Platform Studio in RAD 9.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365818/problems-install-mobilefirst-platform-studio-in-rad-9-0-0)

In addition, Eclipse Juno is not supported as well by MobileFirst Platform. Use Eclipse Java EE Kepler or Luna.

Answer (score 0):

currently I have installed correctly in Eclipse Juno 4.2.2 and works OK
https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-hybrid-development-7-0/ (this web address confirms the compatibility)

I created a project type MobileFirst Project, is all front-end and I have created a template HTML5. Now I want to package HTML5 / CSS3 templates, APK using a MobileFirst, then try it in my terminal Android LG7.

I am basing on this website, to try to generate the APK:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc/appcenter/t_publishing_worklight_applicati.html
but I get the following error when posting and try to generate the APK:
An error ocurred while attemping to publish an application to the IBM Application Center server.
Verify that the URL (protocol, host, port number and context) is correct for the server to which you attempt to connect.
These setting are available in the IBM Application Center preferences page.

It seems that I do not have active IBM Application Server and I do not know how to activate it, any idea?

Thank you very much for your help.